How do you make an authenticated Axios HTTPS GET & POST request via proxy service with BUN?
I am stuck with Error 407 Proxy Authentication Required even though I have my credentials properly set.
Here's my code.
     axios.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json',
    {
      proxy: {
        host:  'some.proxy.com', 
        port: '1000',
        protocol: 'https:',
        auth: {
          username:  'proxyUsername',
          password: 'proxyPassword'
        }
      },
    },).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data); 
     }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

Here's the error I am getting:
  message: "Request failed with status code 407",
  name: "AxiosError",
  code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    data: "Proxy Authentication Required\n",
  },
....
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON],
  isAxiosError: true,
  toString: [Function: toString],
}
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 407

Here's how the headers look like:
Headers {
      "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "user-agent": "axios/1.7.3",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br",
      "proxy-authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx=",
      "host": "some.host.com",
    },

Some things I have tried
new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

and
  const tunelAgent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
    proxy: {
      host: 'proxy.host.com',
      port: 1003,
      proxyAuth: `username:password`,
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  });

None of these work. I also tried the following libraries
require('hpagent')
require('http-proxy-agent')
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'https-proxy-agent';

None of the above even routed the request to the proxy service. I have no idea how others got them to work. In the end the axios way of setting proxy seemed to route the requests.
proxy: {
        host:  'some.proxy.com', 
        port: '1000',
        protocol: 'https:',
        auth: {
          username:  'proxyUsername',
          password: 'proxyPassword'
        }
      }

It is interesting however to note that if I make a get request over http There's no error. that is the following code works:
 axios.get('http://api.ipify.org?format=json')
...

Full disclosure.
I have tried this with Got as well. Same issues. However Axios seems more promising.
I have tried two different proxy serces, SOAX & SMARTPROXY. I get almost the same error.
SOAX would sometimes return
UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT: unable to get issuer certificate
I have run out of ideas. I need help.
Thank you!
Important update:
I am using bun and just discovered that this is actually an issue with bun. Everything works when I run tests with node
Github issue link
